# Design a data structure that use hash and support compare

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, hash

I am looking for help with designing an algorithm that supports:

> initiation(M) Given Set of M unique natural number initialize the data
>   structure in O(f(n)) f is some polynomial function
>    lookUP(x) given a natural number find if x in S
>   in O(1). find Kth(k) return the kth largest number in S in O(1).

the question seemed to me quite easy when I tried to use hash to support O(1) operations, but then I recalled that hash tables does not support compare between elements, I know i can sort the array in O(n^2) and i finish.

Is there a much quicker solution for f(n) as polynomial O(f(n)) init?

Comment: What is `f`? You can sort faster (`n log n`) and probably this is the solution you search for, no hashes.

Comment: edited: f must be polynomial function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know i can sort the array in O(n^2) and i finish.

Sorting can be done faster, in O(nlogn), where n is the size of your problem. An example of such an algorithm is [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Average-case_analysis).

---

The data structure can be an array, where you sort it with cost O(nlogn). Then you can index it for the largest k-th element in O(1) time.

However, in order to search for any x, you will have to use Binary Search, which costs O(logn).

But your elements are unique. So, you could use an index array, where for example if your input was [1, 2, 3, 5], then your boolean index array would be [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], where 0 states that the number in that index is not present in your input. That way you could look up for every x at O(1) time.

But now the find the largest k-th element would require to go to the k-th index, check that slot, and if it's empty, then check the next slot, until you find a 1, meaning that this slot's number is present in our input. This will cost O(m), where m is the number of empty slots you will encounter after reaching the k-th index, which, on average, should be small, and can be assumed to be constant, yielding a time complexity of O(1).